# Elegant environment handling in Nest.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, environment-variables, nestjs

I'm exploring using Nest.js for a critical application that currently has very little test-coverage. We need to make decisions based on environment flags, mostly loading additional express middleware, different loggin configuration etc. I'm using the approach to environment variables as [described in the documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration), but am a bit unsure of how to elegantly (isolated, testable) handle further branching. I could handle all of this in my root module's `configure` hook, but feel like it'd get messy, even if I isolate it into individual methods, and there might be a better solution out there. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! ✌️

Answer (score 16):

This is how I solved when configuring the project and also an example of mongoose connection
**config/config.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';

@Module({
  providers: [ConfigService],
  exports: [ConfigService],
})
export class ConfigModule {}
```

As the .env file will not be used for production
**config/config.service.ts**

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as fs from 'fs';

export class ConfigService {
  MONGODB_URI: string;
  private readonly envConfig: { [key: string]: string };

  constructor() {
    if (
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ||
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'staging'
    ) {
      this.envConfig = {
        MONGODB_URI: process.env.MONGODB_URI,
      };
    } else {
      this.envConfig = dotenv.parse(fs.readFileSync('.env'));
    }
  }

  get(key: string): string {
    return this.envConfig[key];
  }
}
```

**database/database.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { databaseProviders } from './database.providers';

@Module({
  imports: [...databaseProviders],
  exports: [...databaseProviders],
})
export class DatabaseModule {
}
```

**database/database.providers.ts**

```
import { ConfigModule } from '../config/config.module';
import { ConfigService } from '../config/config.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

export const databaseProviders = [
  MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
    imports: [ConfigModule],
    inject: [ConfigService],
    useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
      uri: config.get('MONGODB_URI'),
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    }),
  }),
];
```

Comment: this is giving following error `Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MongooseModuleOptions (?)`